# High explained variance but low p-value in output of factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

I'm trying to perform a factor analysis on some survey data (bit new to the subject) using R's built-in `factanal` function, but I'm failing to interpret its output. My approach was to first perform a PCA to estimate the number of significant axes of variation in the data and then to take this as the number of factors in the function call. However, I obtain a p-value of 0 for the chi-squared test (which probably means the value is below machine precision). If I'm not mistaken, this would mean that this number of factors is not sufficient.

However the SS of the loadings is high for this number (Cumulative Var is 0.886), and the p-value does not increase by adding more variables. What am I misunderstanding here?

Output:

```r
Call:
factanal(x = ., factors = 2, scores = "Bartlett", rotation = "promax",     nstart = 100)

Uniquenesses:
     extInv      conseq       affin intrinsieke       focus    zelfExpl 
      0.086       0.308       0.082       0.135       0.069       0.120 
  explBrdte    explDpte     toewijd        tijd        afh1 
      0.080       0.093       0.073       0.074       0.005 

Loadings:
            Factor1 Factor2
extInv               0.921 
conseq      -0.205  -0.723 
affin        0.424   0.696 
intrinsieke -0.451   1.031 
focus        0.843   0.230 
zelfExpl     1.039  -0.460 
explBrdte    1.015  -0.153 
explDpte     0.756   0.338 
toewijd      0.831   0.247 
tijd         0.913   0.105 
afh1         1.002         

               Factor1 Factor2
SS loadings      6.351   3.392
Proportion Var   0.577   0.308
Cumulative Var   0.577   0.886

Factor Correlations:
        Factor1 Factor2
Factor1    1.00   -0.43
Factor2   -0.43    1.00

Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 6376.64 on 34 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0
```